# Why won't C++ project automatically rebuild when C# project on which it depends is modified?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, build

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution which includes a C# project `Addin` and a C++ project `Shim`. If I make a change to `Addin` (C#), I want `Shim` (C++) to rebuild, but I can't seem to achieve it. When I press F5, `Addin` is rebuilt but `Shim` is not. If I `Rebuild Solution` then it's fine, but there are many other projects in the solution and it takes too long to do this every time.

I'm running Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 on 64-bit Windows Pro 8.0 with a 64-bit processor.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Making `Shim` depend on `Addin` via 'Project Dependencies...'
- Setting `Shim` to reference `Addin`
- (Having added the reference) Setting 'Reference Assembly Output' and 'Link Library Dependencies' to True
- Adding both the project folder and the output folder of `Addin` to 'Additional Include Directories' under `Shim`'s properties => Config => C/C++
- Reading this article: [Visual Studio 2012 doesn't build project on run when its dependencies change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574283/visual-studio-2012-doesnt-build-project-on-run-when-its-dependencies-change) (no good)
- Reading this article: [VS 2012 Does Not Build Dependent Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879774/vs-2012-does-not-build-dependent-project) (changing the intermediate folder for `Shim` to a new folder didn't
  work)
- Checking that `Addin` is being rebuilt properly by checking the `obj` and `bin` folders (it is)
- Checking whether there are any changes to the `obj` and `bin` folders of `Shim` (there are not)
- Reading these articles: [Visual Studio / MSBUILD does not update .lib files when sources are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583703/visual-studio-msbuild-does-not-update-lib-files-when-sources-are-updated) and [Executable not rebuilt but object files recompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182203/executable-not-rebuilt-but-object-files-recompiled) (not relevant since `Shim` rebuilds correctly if I modify it)
- Checking the build output log. The only warning is that `Project file contains ToolsVersion="12.0". This toolset is unknown or missing.`, which I believe is an unrelated NuGet (package manager) error because I'm running VS2012 rather than VS2013.
- Reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx#sectionToggle6 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx, which seem to suggest I've done the necessary things.

Plus googling extensively and looking through as many VS settings as I can think of.

I know that I can force the rebuild by right-clicking and selecting 'Project only' => Rebuild, but it's easy to forget so I'd really like to solve this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may just need to clean the c++ project before you build it in order for it  to pull the updated c# output.  I believe the "Rebuild" action basically performs a "Clean" followed by a "Build" and that may be why the Project Rebuild is working for you.

Comment: If I manually clean and build (or rebuild) the C++ project, it's fine; the problem is that I want this to happen automatically when I press F5 if I have changed the C# project on which it depends.

Comment: Have you looked under Project/Project Build Order to ensure that both projects are listed and ordered correctly?

Comment: I believe this is where I ended up when I encountered a similar issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/34fcc251-b6fe-4878-8274-fa094ae34151/how-do-i-set-the-build-order-of-projects-in-visual-studio-solution?forum=winformssetup

Comment: Yes, the build order is correct: `Addin` appears halfway down the list, immediately followed by `Shim`.

Comment: What happens if you clean the solution, then manually build each project in the desired order (this should already work), but then make a change to the c# project, and F5?  I'm wondering if maybe the building is somehow out of sync and ignoring the order.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing: the C++ project does not get rebuilt, despite being dependent on the C# project. If I 'Rebuild Solution', the build order is honoured.